# Why is TableView not showing anything.

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a class with a tableView. I get no build errors, but when I try to run the app, after I add a new item, nothing appears to happen. Here's the code:

In .h

```
@interface entriesViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *TableView;


-(IBAction)startEditing:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)newItem:(id)sender;
@end
```

In .m

```
#import "entriesViewController.h"
#import "LEItemStore.h"
#import "LEItem.h"

@interface entriesViewController ()

@end

@implementation entriesViewController
@synthesize TableView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        [TableView setDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [TableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(IBAction)startEditing:(id)sender {

    if ([TableView isEditing])
    {
        [TableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];


    }
    else
    {
        [TableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[LEItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }

    LEItem *p = [[[LEItemStore sharedStore] allItems]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[p description]];

    return cell;
}

-(IBAction)newItem:(id)sender {
    LEItem *newItem = [[LEItemStore sharedStore] createItem];
    [TableView reloadData];
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        LEItemStore *ps = [LEItemStore sharedStore];
        NSArray *items = [ps allItems];
        LEItem *p = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [ps removeItem:p];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    [[LEItemStore sharedStore] moveItemAtIndex:[sourceIndexPath row] toIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    //NSArray *items = [[LEItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
    //BNRItem *selectedItem = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self TableView]reloadData];
}
```

It would appear as if the TableView isn't reloading it's data. By the way, all connections have been made. Absolutely nothing appears. Just my Toolbar, the TableView does not change even after I added an item.

Comment: Can you put NSLogs in your numberOfRowsInSection? Make sure the value you are returning there is > 0

Comment: Are you binding the table view to an array controller? Otherwise you do not provide any method to assign the content values (see UITableViewDataSource).

Comment: It won't return anything. It appears that the delegate method isn't getting called at all. Why is that?

Comment: Try to set the delegate in the awakeFromNib method instead of initWithNibName:bundle .

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri, I don't believe so. The only connection I have made between the TableView and my other code is property that declares a TableView. I did see a dataSource, but am unaware of how to use it. I was following the BigNerdRanch guide, and I created an app in that tutorial which did a very similar thing, but did not seem to use a dataSource. However, that class was a sub of UITableViewController.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri, using awakeFromNib did not help. Same result.

Comment: Where is your table view created? In a xib file or storyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so after clearing this in the comments, your problem is that you haven't set the data source (you can also do this with an array controller).
So you set the delegate and the data source:

```
[TableView setDelegate:self];
[TableView setdataSource: self];
```

Then you declare the class to also implement the UITableViewDataSource protocol.
And you provide the two fondamental methods (also optional methods are welcome):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

This is an example of a simple data source implementation that just has one label saying hello:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
    UILabel* label= cell.textLabel;
    label.text= @"Hello";
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

But now you know how to provide a more complex data source: if you have an array you can read the index path and then set the label using the objectAtIndex method.

Comment: Still nothing happened. It would seem like the dataSource needs to be set to LEItemStore, but when I try to do that I get an error, and still nothing happens.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I just needed to do what you said and set the dataSource to self. But then in the xib file I needed to make a connection to datasource and delegate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this, but if you are using controller as data source then you need to specify interface for UITableViewDataSource.

Try changing:

```
@interface entriesViewController : UIViewController
   <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

Set delegate and dataSource for tableView in viewDidLoad to controller instance e.g.

```
TableView.delegate = self;
TableView.dataSource = self;
```

You can also implement UITableViewDataSource interface on LEItemStore classs. If you do so, then you need to set dataSource property to instance of LEItemStore.

```
TableView.delegate = self;
TableView.dataSource = [LEItemStore sharedStore];
```

Comment: Setting the dataSource to LEItemStore seems like what I want to do. However, when I do that I get an error saying that LEItemStore is of incompatible type UITableViewDataSource.

Answer (score -1):

My Problem was : I didnt defined the delegate and dataSource !

TableView.delegate = self;
TableView.dataSource = self;

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers. Both other answers already present this solution.